# django webrtc and django channels

Tags: python, django, webrtc, django-channels

I've been on the lookout for a comprehensive step-by-step tutorial guiding me through the process of creating a video chat app using Django, WebRTC, and Django Channels. Despite my efforts, I haven't come across any truly helpful resources. While I've consulted the Django Channels documentation, I'm struggling to grasp how all the components seamlessly come together.

It's worth mentioning that I'm not a novice with Django, having used it for some time. However, I've never delved into the realm of Django Channels or implemented live chat or video features before, making this a novel experience for me.

I'd greatly appreciate any assistance, insights, or suggestions you can offer. Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Can you explain a little bit more about what you are trying to build? With django channels you will only be able to build a P2P application. If you want to do multiple participant rooms or anything bigger you will need dedicated WebRTC software. This all depends on the toplogy you want to work with https://webrtcforthecurious.com/docs/08-applied-webrtc/#webrtc-topologies